# Search unique value with DataTable search()

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a table. In that table there is a `status` column which contains text `active`, `inactive` and `warning`. I have made a filter for the `status` column, but the problem is when the filter is `active` then the `inactive` rows are also shown.

How do I make it so that if the user selects `active`, `inactive` is not shown?

```html
<select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Select Status</option>
  <option value="active">active</option>
  <option value="inactive">inactive</option>
  <option value="warning">warning</option>
</select>
```

```js
$("#status", this).on("click", function() {
  if (SomeTable.column(4).search() !== this.value) {
    SomeTable
      .column(4)
      .unique()
      .search(this.value)
      .draw();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Its better to use change function on select instead of click

```
<select name="status" id="status" onchange="filterData(event)" class="form-control">
<option value="">Select Status</option>
<option value="active">active</option>
<option value="inactive">inactive</option>
<option value="warning">warning</option>
```

----------------------function be like----------------------------

```
function filterData(event) {
    debugger
    var status = event.target.value;
    var rows = $("#myTable tr");
    rows.each(function (index, element) {
        if (!status)
            $(element).show();
        if (index > 0 && status) {
            if (status.toLowerCase() !== element.children[3].innerText.toLowerCase())
                $(element).hide();
            else
                $(element).show();
        }
    })
}
```

--------table------------------

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Active</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
    <td>Warning</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
    <td>InActive</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>Warning</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>InActive</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
    <td>Active</td>
</tr>
```

----------Provide a name to your table also check the child element that row has the action active,inactive,warning---

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because by default DataTables `search()` just looks for the string *anywhere* within the cell text. As such you search for 'active' also finds the 'inactive' cells.

To fix this, use a regular expression to perform the search, using `^` and `$` to anchor the value:

```
$("#status", this).on("change", function() {
  if (SomeTable.column(4).search() !== this.value) {
    SomeTable
      .column(4)
      .unique()
      .search('^' + this.value + '$', true, false)
      .draw();
  }
});
```

For more information on this, see the [DataTables `search()` documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()#Types)

Comment: sorry, sir, I used data tables and regex for the first time, 
so when I added the code, it became ^active$ and of course, it wasn't in the status column

Comment: `^active$` is correct, it's a regular expression. Did you also set the other boolean flags?

Comment: yes, i set  processing: true, serverSide: false, and orderable:false in each column

Comment: @misry Remove the .unique() part from above code, and it will search the way you want.